# Django: how to startapp inside an "apps" folder

Tags: django

I feel like I must be looking over something obvious because I am having trouble finding anything online about this. But basically here it is, I have a django Project, and I would like to store my apps inside of an apps folder, like thus...

```
myproject/
    client-side/
        media/
        static/
        templates/
    apps/
        app1/
        app2/
        etc. 
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    etc. (rest of root directory)
```

but have been unable to figure out how to >>>python manage.py startapp newapp and have it placed into the /apps/ folder. Is it ok to simply ok to startapp at the root level and manually move them into the /apps/ folder?

I greatly appreciate your thoughts and answers.

FYI running python 3.4.2 and Django 1.9.5 on Windows 10

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can specify the app's directory as a second parameter:

```
python manage.py startapp <app_name> <app_directory>
```

Note that no directory will be created, the app's files will be created directly in the specified directory. Example:

```
python manage.py startapp myapp apps/myapp
```

Will result in the given directory structure:

```
apps
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

Also note that the command won't create the directory for you.

Edit: as another (now deleted) answer pointed out, running the command from the `apps` directory would also work:

```
cd apps
python ../manage.py startapp myapp
```

Comment: This worked like a perfectly! Thank you aumo. Also have to mention an answer posted by @xyres (who deleted his comment for some reason) that running >>>python ../manage.py startapp newapp from the /apps/ folder worked as well.

Comment: @Tarrant Yeah, I deleted that because this was the better answer as it makes use of Django's built-in feature.

Comment: @xyres thank you for clarifying that the listed answer is the more appropriate answer - would not have known otherwise...Once again thank you aumo for pointing out a great answer.

Comment: If I move the app into the apps folder, How can I register the app in the projects INSTALLED_APPS. cause each time I try to this, and the run server commands tells ImportError no module named apps.myapp.apps.Config???

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper I just tried it with Django 3.2.7 and it worked as expected, what is the exact error message you are. getting?

Comment: If you are getting an ImportError, make sure you update your app name on `apps.py` file. In this example it should be `name = 'apps.myapp'`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `django-admin` command as well.

```
cd apps && django-admin startapp app_1
```

this will work as well